# IIS 7.5. Can't disable Url Rewriting rules (I deleted rules but they still affect)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I develop ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I've downloaded UrlRewriting module and created some rules for my website locally.
Next i published this website on the Internet to check performance. Thats ok.
Then i continued my work locally again. I commented code block in the web.config file regarding these rules.
So there are no rules in IIS Manager too.
The problem is that rules still affect! For example, i defined "Canonical hostname rule" to redirect browser to "www.*" site name. So this rule still affect, i.e. local IIS server redirect my locally running website to the real one on the Internet.
Also i installed IIS Express to try it out too. Result is the same.
I cant figure it out where the problem is.
So, there are no rewrite rules on IIS server and IIS Express, but they still affect.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my question :)
The reason was my browser cache. I just cleaned it up and the problem dissapeared.
Anyway it is strange thing. I didnt know that browser saves such rules in cache.

Comment: The browser doesn't cache the rules themselves, but keeps tracks of the requested (rewritten) URLs. For efficiency, the browser detects if the URL has been requested; if that URL was rewritten, then it serves the content of that URL previously served. Hope this helps, R/

Comment: Yes, clearing the cache fixed it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Late answer is late. Most likely the redirect was "permanent" so a 301, then it will be cached in the browsers. If you want it to be temporary redirect with code 307.

Answer (score 2):

The URL Rewrite module seams to my a little buggy when the configuration changes becouse the loaded configuration doesn't refreshed until the IIS isn't restarted.

Comment: Or the current application pool recycled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the IIS in order to apply the changes, then you should clear the browser cache.